# one plus one update from 5.0 to 6.0

Tags: cyanogenmod, oneplus-one

I'm update my device (one plus one) to 6.0 and it works fine

but I cannot open caller and make call , also I cannot send sms (message)

my contact numbers & text message  sometimes disappeard.

I don't know what is the problem?

android version: 6.0.1
cyanogen OS version : 13.0-ZNH0EAS26M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made reset factory to my android device , and It works fine